# Getting the purchase/consumption status of a Google Play item from C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to get the purchase/consumption status of a microtransaction that my user has bought via their app. The user authorizes it, and gives my server a token to know that the transaction has been processed, and now I need to double check that it's actually been made. To do so, I think I'm supposed to use [purchases.products.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get), whose Rest API recommends I set up OAuth. For server-server communication, the docs recommend I use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account), which recommend I use the Google API to handle JWT signing.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to set up the `purchases.products.get` request from my C# server. According to the docs, I need to create a [service object](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python) for the API that I want to call ([AndroidPublisherService](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2/latest/api/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2.AndroidPublisherService.html)). [From browsing the API](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2/latest/api/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2.PurchasesResource.ProductsResource.GetRequest.html), it looks like I can create GetRequest which is an object with the right arguments... but how do I actually send it to Google and get a response?

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(CRED_FILENAME);
var service = new AndroidPublisherService(
    new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "UnityIAPTransactionHandler"
    });

// What do I do with this???
new PurchasesResource.ProductsResource.GetRequest(service, PACKAGE_NAME, @"com.appname.coin_12000", @"Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it: It's not a function on the Service, it's on the newly formed request object. My code now looks like this:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(CRED_FILENAME);
service = new AndroidPublisherService(
    new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "UnityIAPTransactionHandler"
    });

var request = new PurchasesResource.ProductsResource.GetRequest(service, PACKAGE_NAME, @"com.astatos.coin_12000", @"Test");
var purchase = request.Execute();
```

And it executes! Although now I have to figure out other errors being thrown, I hope this helps somebody else too.